# E-mailed report misses a column

Tags: reports

I have created Contribution report which also has one **Custom Field** column (Membership Type).

When I open the report, I see all columns.

---

[image]

---

But when I setup Email Delivery and receive the report as CSV, it lacks the Membership Type column.

[image]

Why could this be?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out finally. The Email Delivery was called by the user with different permissions that the one who was logged in. Adding Permission **CiviCRM: access all custom data** solved the problem.